# Android - IOException Error In Log

Tags: android, error-handling, android-asynctask, ioexception

I'm suffering from the strange situation. The problem is that, My application is using the Asynctask to fetch data from my custom web service. Here, on the same task, it is giving the IOException error in the logs. However, task is working fine and returning all the data required to gather from server. Meaning while, It seems asynctask is working fine but in logs giving "IOException". Here are the logs

```
03-22 18:39:50.880: D/dalvikvm(586): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2666K, 54% free 4661K/10119K, external 2108K/2633K, paused 73ms
03-22 18:39:54.370: D/PhoneWindow(586): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view android.widget.EditText@405438d0 has no id.
03-22 18:39:58.352: E/Exception at FETCH EMPLOYEE TASK(586): java.io.IOException: Not Found
03-22 18:40:00.210: D/dalvikvm(586): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1189K, 53% free 4778K/10119K, external 2113K/2215K, paused 9ms+10ms
03-22 18:40:03.670: D/dalvikvm(586): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1360K, 53% free 4767K/10119K, external 2108K/2215K, paused 9ms+5ms
03-22 18:40:07.230: E/Exception at FETCH EMPLOYEE TASK(586): java.io.IOException: Not Found
03-22 18:40:09.070: D/dalvikvm(586): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1129K, 51% free 5041K/10119K, external 2108K/2215K, paused 8ms+6ms
03-22 18:40:12.810: E/Exception at FETCH EMPLOYEE TASK(586): java.io.IOException: Not Found
03-22 18:40:14.610: D/dalvikvm(586): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1312K, 49% free 5231K/10119K, external 2108K/2215K, paused 9ms+6ms
03-22 18:40:21.220: D/dalvikvm(586): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1354K, 47% free 5437K/10119K, external 2108K/2215K, paused 9ms+6ms
03-22 18:40:22.210: E/Exception at FETCH EMPLOYEE TASK(586): java.io.IOException: Not Found
03-22 18:40:26.880: D/dalvikvm(586): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2246K, 53% free 4803K/10119K, external 2108K/2215K, paused 19ms+7ms
03-22 18:40:27.891: E/Exception at FETCH EMPLOYEE TASK(586): java.io.IOException: Not Found
03-22 18:40:32.540: D/dalvikvm(586): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1319K, 52% free 4896K/10119K, external 2108K/2215K, paused 8ms+6ms
03-22 18:40:36.183: E/Exception at FETCH EMPLOYEE TASK(586): java.io.IOException: Not Found
03-22 18:40:38.081: D/dalvikvm(586): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1293K, 51% free 5000K/10119K, external 2108K/2215K, paused 8ms+8ms
03-22 18:40:40.330: I/dalvikvm(586): Jit: resizing JitTable from 2048 to 4096
03-22 18:40:40.780: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(586): finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
03-22 18:40:43.390: E/Exception at FETCH EMPLOYEE TASK(586): java.io.IOException: Not Found
03-22 18:40:44.790: D/dalvikvm(586): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1715K, 54% free 4700K/10119K, external 2108K/2215K, paused 9ms+7ms
```

Here my Asynctask.

```
public class FetchEmployeeTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, VO_EmployeeHolder> {

VO_EmployeeHolder vEholder  = new VO_EmployeeHolder();
Core core                   = new Core();

String _empId,_username,_password;
String _data,_url;
private static final String KEY_ID          = "id";
private static final String KEY_FNAME       = "first-name";
private static final String KEY_LNAME       = "last-name";
private static final String KEY_DESIG       = "title";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL       = "email-address";
private static final String KEY_AVATAR      = "avatar-url";
private static final String KEY_CELLNO      = "phone-number-mobile";

@Override
protected VO_EmployeeHolder doInBackground(String... params) {

    this._empId         = params[0];
    this._username      = params[1];
    this._password      = params[2];
    this._url           = "https://somedomainhere.to.place/man/"+this._empId+".xml";

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpHost _thost = new HttpHost("somedomainhere.to.place",443,"https");
    try {
         ((AbstractHttpClient) httpclient).getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                new org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope(_thost.getHostName(),_thost.getPort()),
                new org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials(this._username, this._password));

        response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(this._url));
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            InputStream _Istream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            Document _Document = DomTaskParse(_Istream);
            NodeList _nodeRecord = _Document.getElementsByTagName("person");
            loadEmployee(_nodeRecord);
        } else {
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }
    } catch(ClientProtocolException cpe) {
        Log.e("ClientProtocolException @ FPT",cpe.toString());
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Exception at FETCH EMPLOYEE TASK",ex.toString());
    }


    return this.vEholder;
}

private void loadEmployee(NodeList nList) {
    Element e = (Element) nList.item(0);
    this.vEholder._id               = core.getValue(e, KEY_ID);
    this.vEholder._fname            = core.getValue(e, KEY_FNAME);
    this.vEholder._lname            = core.getValue(e, KEY_LNAME);
    this.vEholder._designation      = core.getValue(e, KEY_DESIG);
    this.vEholder._email            = core.getValue(e, KEY_EMAIL);
    this.vEholder._avatar           = core.getValue(e, KEY_AVATAR);
    this.vEholder._cellno           = core.getValue(e, KEY_CELLNO);
}

private Document DomTaskParse(InputStream _Istream) {
    try {
        return new DomParserTask().execute(_Istream).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Android's Garbage Collector is running in the background. DVM is clearing the unwanted data by calling the GC and also increasing the allotted RAM for this particular Application. The RAM will be increased until it reaches the maximum RAM that can be given to an application and after that if it still wants to extend then DVM will throws Out of Memory Exception.

Comment: So its positive or negative? What should I do now?

Comment: No need to bother. DVM will take care of such issues. But you should take care of the memory usage. As much as you can reduce the memory usage. As this is a smart phone not at all a system or server to handle larger memory. Optimize every thing that you can.

Comment: If this is what you are looking for then select this as a correct one.

Comment: Not going ahead because still don't get answer about `03-22 18:39:58.352: E/Exception at FETCH EMPLOYEE TASK(586): java.io.IOException: Not Found`. Why this is so if it is working fine ?

Comment: Can You check the line 

couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view android.widget.EditText@405438d0 has no id.

Comment: Can you please check the EditText in the layouts which don't has ID ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9205/discussion-between-pavandroid-and-hamza-waqas)